# Why should I use the dbDacFx provider at all?

Tags: sql-server, iis, webdeploy, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I'm looking at ways to automatically publish a dacpac whenever I deploy my web application to IIS.

One of those ways is through Web Deploy itself, using the dbDacFx provider.
See: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/dbdacfx-provider-for-incremental-database-publishing

Some of the examples that they give for syncing two databases look like this:

```
msdeloy.exe -Verb:Sync ^
-Source:dbDacFx="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=OldDatabase; User ID=sa; Password=P@$$W0rd" ^
-Dest:dbDacFx="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=NewDatabase; User ID=sa; Password=P@$$W0rd"
```

```
msdeloy.exe -Verb:Sync ^
-Source:dbDacFx="C:\Users\Admininstrator\Documents\database.dacpac" ^
-Dest:dbDacFx="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=NewDatabase; User ID=sa; Password=P@$$W0rd"
```

My question is why on earth would I not use SqlPackage.exe for this?

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish ^
/SourceConnectionString:"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=OldDatabase; User ID=sa; Password=P@$$W0rd" ^
/TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=NewDatabase; User ID=sa; Password=P@$$W0rd"
```

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish ^
/SourceFile:"C:\Users\Admininstrator\Documents\database.dacpac" ^
/TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=NewDatabase; User ID=sa; Password=P@$$W0rd"
```

Web Deploy doesn't bring anything new to the table as far as I can tell. Why does the dbDacFx provider even exist?

Things I already considered:

- Web Deploy's dbDacFx runs on the application server instead of the machine that triggers the deployment

  - Non-administrator deploys are possible through wmsvc delegation rules (but then why do the examples use 'sa' instead of integrated security?)
- Both msdeploy.exe and SqlPackage.exe support parameterization through xml configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the only way you will get a definite answer as to why it exists is to find someone on the msdeploy team and ask them.

The thing that is so awesome about dacpacs is that the SSDT team have built these api's (DacFX) and made them available to everyone so people are free to do this sort of thing and if it helps people who already use msdeploy deploy dacpacs then why not?

I have seen a few different implementations, visual studio has publish + schema compare which both use the DacFx.

If you already use sqlpackage and want to use it go for it.

Comment: I'm already using msdeploy with MSBuild, but I can't find a way to integrate dbDacFx in my current workflow.

Comment: Is "Web Deploy doesn't bring anything new to the table as far as I can tell. Why does the dbDacFx provider even exist?" your question or is your question something else?? (i'm a little confused :) )

Comment: It is. I need to know if there's any compelling reason to make msdeploy's dbDacFx work for me, or if I should just script my own deployment handlers instead.

Comment: ok cool, looking at http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/dbdacfx-provider-for-incremental-database-publishing there are no additional benefits it is just that they have other providers and it is something they offer people who use msdeploy - personally I would just use sqlpackage.exe as you only have one place for things to go wrong / file bugs!